# Is there a way I can have multiple number limits on different textboxes?

Tags: html

I'm working on a basic scoring unit. I have text boxes and want the user to only instert numbers in a certain set, and if a number that is outside the set gets entered an error comes up saying 'only these numbers can be entered'. There are multiple sets of numbers though. Is it possible to have more than one? here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="text"size="3"></p>
<h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="text"size="3"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="text"size="3"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="text"size="3"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="text"size="3"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points:  <input type="text"size="3"> /90</p>
<h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="text"size="3"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="text"size="3"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="text"size="3"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points:   <input type="text"size="3"> /90</p>
<p> Over All Score:<input type="text"size="3"> /90</p>
<p> Award Assigned:</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Technique:   /35
Choreography:   /15
Performance:    /25
Precision:    /15

There are text boxes next to the slash and number

Comment: could you provide an example of one or two inputs and what sets of numbers are valid?

Comment: Dance Number:  

Judge 1

Comments

 
Technique:   /35

Choreography:   /15

Performance:  /25

Precision:   /15

Total Points:  /90

Comment: I recommend you now also look at automating the totals in javascript - you could ask a question about that next or search the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the input type number (as these are scores) and set a maximum and minimum value that will be enforced by the browser.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="number"size="3"></p>
<h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="number" min="0" max="35"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="number" min="0" max="25"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input type="number" min="0" max="90">   /90</p>
<h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="number" min="0" max="35"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="number" min="0" max="25"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points:  <input type="number" min="0" max="90">  /90</p>
<h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br />
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input type="number" min="0" max="35"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input type="number" min="0" max="25"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input type="number" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points:  <input type="number" min="0" max="90"> /90</p>
<p> Over All Score:  <input type="number" min="0" max="90"> /90</p>
<p> Award Assigned:</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that HTML5 :) comes to the rescue :) I did not know input type can be number.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can, I do not know if you can using css but using javascript you can, using on key pressed. Like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>insert page</title></head>
<body onkeypress="alert("HELL")">
    <textarea id='textbox1' onkeypress="countLetters(this, 15)">
    </textarea>

    <textarea id='textbox2' onkeypress="countLetters(this, 25)"></textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var textbox1 = textbox2 = textbox3 = textbox4 = 0;

function countLetters(element, limit) {

    if(element.id == 'textbox1') {
        if(element.value.length > limit) {
            element.disabled=true;
        } else {
            textbox1++;
        }
   } else if (element.id == 'textbox2') {
       if(element.value.length > limit) {
            element.disabled=true;
       } else {
           textbox2++;
       }
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my previous code was not working, I typed it all on cell and plus copied some other code. Notice that now variables are out of the function this will help increment them ;) and we disable input completely instead of using string shortening.